# Wind turbine 500 W

Tags: voltage, power, current

I have an A wing wind turbine 500 W. Does this mean it can produce max power 500W? How can I know the max voltage and the max current that can be produced by A wing wind turbine 500 W?

For the spec you can see: 
http://www.awing-i.com/english/500W_wind_turbine.html

I also use Luminous Accumulator 12 V 100 Ah (if it is needed for calculation or something else)
https://www.luminousindia.com/batteries.html

Comment: The AWing page you linked states that the output is suitable for charging 24 volt batteries, and that that model can produce 500 Watts.  That page has an email link for the company - they would be better placed to answer your questions than anyone here.

Comment: That page includes a lik to [this PDF](http://www.awing-i.com/english/E500T.pdf) which provide some control / wattage with wind speed indications.   Assume 24V out (note it says it contains a DC DC inverter). Assue wattage quoted is optimistic

Answer (score 1):

When one reads the data sheet, it answers some questions, and prompts others.

The output is rated at 500W in a 14m/s wind speed. In higher winds, up to its 60m/s survival speed, you may get more, depending on whether it has any controls that limit it. At lower winds speeds, down to the cut-in speed of a few m/s, you will get less, a lot less.

The output voltage is rated as 24v charging, but no wind speed is mentioned. You might expect that is also at 14m/s, at which you will be getting 500W, or around 20 amps.

What happens at higher or lower wind speeds? Is the voltage controlled to be constant, or does it vary with the wind speed? Does it have a built in charging control, that can limit the current, and to what chemistry of batteries?

Does the turbine charge at 24v? Or is it '*suitable* for charging at 24v' ('when used with our optional ...')

You need to grub around on their website for more details, and if you can't find them, contact the manufacturer. If it was stated to be a simple permanent magnet generator, then it would be possible to calculate what would happen versus wind speed, at least to first order. As the '24v charging' statement implies some sort of controller in there, you need to find out what it has been designed to do, because frankly, anything the designer thought was useful could be programmed in, as long as the electrical power output doesn't exceed the wind power input ("ye canna break the laws of physics cap'n")

Bear in mind that these guys want to sell their stuff, so it's in their interest to help you use it. If they're smart, then there is already an 'applications' page on their website, showing you how it's intended to be used.